# Is running thousands of thread which contains mostly sleeps, resource-expensive?

Tags: java, multithreading, telegram

I'm developing a telegram api bot.

Players in a chat group will start a game that creates a thread which has the task of processing the game flow.

The bot has different games to play, and each game has different game processing.

For example, one game is a turn-based game. The bot randomly selects one player, and tell them something to do (Out of discussion), and when player's time ends (Usually one minute), the bot will create a poll for other players, and players should vote that the selected player did his work correctly. If more than half players accept, then this process will repeat will other players until all players play once, and then the game ends.

There are also some other games, this one was for introducing only.

Now, The parent game class (abstract) has a `Thread getThread();` method that Childs will override to return their own implementation of their game's process.

Is this method too resource-expensive? Usually, from 10 to 500 game gets running in same time and most of the time that threads spend is `Thread.sleep`, Is it a performance disadvantage?

Comment: Threads do require resources even if they're not doing anything. However if they're not doing anything most of the time, it's probably a better idea to use an architecture that doesn't require you to create lots of sleeping threads for no reason. Such as by scheduling events.

Comment: Why downvoting?

Comment: What architecture do you recommend to use? @Kayaman

Comment: What do you mean by "sleep?"  If you have thousands of threads that literally all call `Thread.sleep(nnnn)` then you might be better off solving your problem with some kind of a `Timer` class instead.  But, if each of your threads is _blocked_, waiting to respond to a different external event (e.g., each one waiting for a different user to make some kind of move) then that's a good use for threads.  If you need so many threads that you're running out of memory or CPU cycles, then it may be time to start thinking about _cluster computing_.

Comment: @jameslarge No, none of the threads rely on another or any other references from other of thread; so this is not a blocking situation. Every game separate from each other, put delays between actions to make the game realistic, and the sleep gets used around 20-30 times in a thread (with actions between each other)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost any code that uses thread.sleep is going to be either resource hungry (because it polls too often) or non-responsive (because it doesn't poll often enough).

Each time `sleep()` is called, the OS needs to schedule a different native thread to run and then perform the thread switch.  This is not a cheap operation.  Multiply this by thousands of thread switches per second, and you will be using a significant percentage of your CPU time in overheads.

A more efficient and responsive approach to multi-threading is to use wait / notify .... or a higher level concurrency construct built on top of wait / notify or the equivalent.

And there are even more performant approaches (e.g. [fork / join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork%E2%80%93join_model), or the [reactor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactor_pattern)) but they will entail a different way of thinking about your problem.  But if you find yourself with an implementation architecture that needs hundreds or thousands of threads, you probably *do* need to rethink.  Each thread uses significant resources (e.g. memory) just by existing.

Comment: So, What is the best practice to implement the thing I want? Reactor pattern is really something bad and not object-oriented.

Comment: "Bad" is not an objective term. "Best practice" is even worse (see http://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/27).   But threads are certainly easier to implement than reactors.  But whatever you do, don't use `sleep` ...

Comment: Thanks for the blog post, I learned valuable lessons. How do I can implement delays between actions with wait / notify? I searched but from things I've seen, they're not related. Correct me if there is a way.

Comment: There is a concurrency class called `Timer`.  Also a lot of concurrency classes (even `Object.wait`) allow you to set a timeout on a blocking action.  I recommend that you read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/ and also review the classes in the `java.util.concurrent` package.